# How can I convert transform column in Pandas using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, eval

I have got a `time column` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: '1 h 50 min', 1: '50 min', 2: '2 h 3 min', 3: '3 min'}})
```

```
        time
0  1 h 50 min
1      50 min
2   2 h 3 min
3       3 min
```

I want the information in seconds like:

```
time
6600
3000
7380
180
```

I was trying to use `regex` and `eval` to evaluate the time in seconds but was not successful what's the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the `regex` to get hr and minute, then convert both to minutes and calculate the sum, finally multiply the result by 60 to get the seconds.

```py
df['time'].str.findall('(\d+)\s*(h|min)').apply(lambda x: sum(int(t)*60 if u=='h' else int(t) for t,u in x))*60
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0    6600
1    3000
2    7380
3     180
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

If you want, you can just have separate columns of hour and minute:

```py
out = df.assign(hours=df['time'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*h'),
          minutes=df['time'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*min')).fillna(0)

         time hours minutes
0  1 h 50 min     1      50
1      50 min     0      50
2   2 h 3 min     2       3
3       3 min     0       3
```

Now , you can just convert them to integer and get the number of seconds:

```py
out['hours'].astype(int)*3600+out['minutes'].astype(int)*60

0    6600
1    3000
2    7380
3     180
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.TimedeltaIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) understands many string forms of durations, so you can pass your column to it directly. It also has `total_seconds` method, so:

```
>>> df["seconds"] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.time).total_seconds()
>>> df

         time  seconds
0  1 h 50 min   6600.0
1      50 min   3000.0
2   2 h 3 min   7380.0
3       3 min    180.0
```